# jQuery Hide and Show multiple Divs with Multiple Buttons

Tags: hide

I have 4 Div containers
I want to have 4 Buttons

When page opens all DIVs are hidden
When the user click a Button a specific DIV opens.
When another button is clicked that original DIV closes and the one corresponding with that button opens and so forth

I searched through the posts and did not find anything like this.  I tried to modify a few but had no luck.

Anyone point me in the direction for example?  Would like to do this in jQuery or JS

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am trying....its sort of working but because there are 4 DIVs I think its getting confused.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$("a").click(function(){
    //alert("dfgfdg");
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
    $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
  });

};


<div>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#slider1_container"> slider 1</a></h3>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#slider2_container"> slider 2</a></h3>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#slider3_container"> slider 3</a></h3>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#slider4_container"> slider 4</a></h3>
</div>



<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;  ">
</div>
<div id="slider2_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;  ">
</div>
<div id="slider3_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;  ">
</div>
<div id="slider4_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;  ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("a").each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       $(this).click(function(){
        //alert("dfgfdg");
        $($this.attr('href')).show();
        $('div').not($this.attr('href')).hide();
      });
   });
```

Working fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0exyjhq3/1/)

Edit:

I don't know what are you trying to achieve right now. I suppose you want content of your div to be visible, so try this:

```
$($this.attr('href')).children().show():
```

Comment: I am soooo close... https://jsfiddle.net/Jaykapalczynski/okemrcgs/15/ In this JS Fiddle I think it all comes down to the hide $('div').not($this.attr('href')).hide();  1. If I comment it our it shows the slider container and does not remove the buttons, BUT it does not hide the other slider containers (DIVs).  2. If I leave it in the code the slider container does not open and the buttons remain.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it to work but had to do this....I know there is an easier way...anyone?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").each(function(){

   var $this = $(this);
   $(this).click(function(){

        $($this.attr('href')).show();
        //$($this.attr('href')).children().show():

        var href = ($this).attr('href');
        alert(href);

        //$('div').not($this.attr('href')).hide();

        if(href == "#slider1_container") {
                    $( "#slider2_container" ).hide();           
                    $( "#slider3_container" ).hide();           
                    $( "#slider4_container" ).hide();
        }
        else if(href == "#slider2_container") {     
                    $( "#slider1_container" ).hide();
                    $( "#slider3_container" ).hide();           
                    $( "#slider4_container" ).hide();
        }
        else if(href == "#slider3_container") {     
                    $( "#slider1_container" ).hide();
                    $( "#slider2_container" ).hide();                   
                    $( "#slider4_container" ).hide();
        }
        else if(href == "#slider4_container") {         
                    $( "#slider1_container" ).hide();
                    $( "#slider2_container" ).hide();           
                    $( "#slider3_container" ).hide();           
        }
        else {
            $alert("broke");
        }               


      });
   });

});
```